# Why is Chrome telling me I have an Unhandled Rejection when I clearly am handling it?

Tags: javascript, promise, uncaught-exception

I am using a "defer" pattern for Javascript promises that lets me return a promise to a calling function, and then at a later time, on some conditions, resolve or reject that promise.

As you can see in my code provided, everything is working as expected EXCEPT for the fact that in the browser, I get an `Unhandled Rejection` error.

```
function promiseGenerator() {
  const deferred = {};

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deferred.resolve = resolve;
    deferred.reject = reject;
  });
  deferred.promise = promise;

  return deferred;
}

const generatedPromise = promiseGenerator();

generatedPromise.promise.then(res => {
  console.log("A string deferred resolved!", res);
});

generatedPromise.promise.then().catch(e => {
  console.log("This is the catch", e);
});

generatedPromise.reject("Oh no");
```

I'm expecting to see `This is the catch Oh no` in the console - and I do. But why am I getting the error? Clearly my rejection **is** being handled!

**NOTE** that I don't (necessarily) want to chain the catch to the `then` because I may want to add this catch somewhere else, separately, in the code

Here is a Codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/embed/deferred-promise-catch-vanilla-pjor9

Comment: Also note that this is usually referred to as the deferred *anti*-pattern. It's almost always unnecessary.

Comment: @JaredSmith why is it almost always unnecessary?

Comment: Because there just aren't that many scenarios (arguably there aren't *any* at all) where you need to settle the Promise from outside like that, and if it's not absolutely necessary then the extra layer of indirection just makes the code harder to follow and use. Settle it in the callback passed to the constructor or by using the static methods on the Promise class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Promise rejections are not handled in the `.then()` callback, when you attach the `then()` callback first and the promise is rejected the error is considered to be unhandled as there is no `catch()` following the `then()`.

The proper way to handle this is to add a `catch()` chained to the `then()`:

```js
function promiseGenerator() {
  const deferred = {};

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deferred.resolve = resolve;
    deferred.reject = reject;
  });
  deferred.promise = promise;

  return deferred;
}

const generatedPromise = promiseGenerator();

//Error from the rejection is handled in the catch
generatedPromise.promise.then(res => {
  console.log("A string deferred resolved!", res);
}).catch(e => {
  console.log("This is the catch", e);
});

generatedPromise.reject("Oh no");
```

Another way is to pass a rejection handler as the second parameter of the `then()` callback to handle the Promise rejection:

```js
function promiseGenerator() {
  const deferred = {};

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deferred.resolve = resolve;
    deferred.reject = reject;
  });
  deferred.promise = promise;

  return deferred;
}

const generatedPromise = promiseGenerator();

//Error from the rejection is handled in the second callback
generatedPromise.promise.then(res => {
  console.log("A string deferred resolved!", res);
},
err => {
  console.log("This is the catch", err);
});

generatedPromise.reject("Oh no");
```

Comment: Yes but as mentioned, I may want to add the catch somewhere else in the code and not necessarily on the main `then`. Or I may want to have an _additional_ rejection catch, etc

Comment: The first part of your answer is plain wrong. It doesn't matter in what order `.catch` and `.then` are called on that promise. You can try running your first snippet, it still produces an unhandled rejection.

Comment: @Bergi I got that part wrong, I fixed it now!

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch errors thrown in the callback you passed to the `new Promise()` constructor, the `catch` block needs to be appended to returned value of `.then()`, not to the promise itself.

```
generatedPromise.promise
  .then(res => {
    console.log("A string deferred resolved!", res);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log("This is the catch", e);
  });
```

The `generatedPromise.reject` object is a reference to the `reject` argument inside the callback you passed to the constructor `(resolve, reject) => {}`.

On the same note, `generatedPromise.promise` is a reference to the object returned by `new Promise()`.

Then only way you can catch an error thrown by calling `genetratedPromise.reject()` is by chaining a `.catch()` to the `.then()`. There is no other way.

Here's another way of seeing this problem:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject('test')
});


promise.catch(err => 'foo'); // throws unhandled promise rejection. Cause you rejected, but didn't catch it after the .then statement

promise.then(() => {}).catch(err => 'foo'); // doesn't throw rejection
```

Comment: I specifically do not want to put it with the `then` because I might want to have this catch in a separate place on its own (i.e. adding an addition action in the event of a `reject`

Comment: I updated my answer to better explain why that cannot be done

Comment: @raphisama That's not possible. The promise created by the `.then()` chain is getting rejected - there's no error handler in between - and on *that* promise you are getting an unhandled rejection. That you did branch the promise chain, and handled the error elsewhere as well, doesn't matter for this promise.

Answer (score -1):

You use catch in a promise chain. 
`generatedPromise.promise.then(res => {
  console.log("A string deferred resolved!", res);
}).catch(error => console.log('error));`

Edit:Someone was faster.

Edit2: Seen comment on other post. There might be a way, but it's not good practice.

```
  function promiseGenerator() {
  const deferred = {};


//do your function stuff here
try{
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deferred.resolve = resolve;

 });
} catch(ex){
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deferred.resolve = resolve(ex);
  });
}

  return deferred;
}
```

This way you have two different results for one promise, other way is to use instead of try catch block, if else statements, but it solely depends on your application.

Comment: This `try`/`catch` - without any `await` - absolutely doesn't handle errors

Comment: That's not true. If you do stuff in try catch block, f.e. divide by zero, catch block is initiated. I don't see a scenario how you would handle errors with await.

Comment: Divide by zero produces `Infinity` or `NaN` in JS, not an exception. But we're talking about promise rejections here, and `try` doesn't catch such asynchronous errors.